# httpdが自動起動しない

Tags: centos, apache

AWSのEC2を使用して、WEBサーバをたちあげています。
chkconfig httpd on で自動起動の設定をおこなっておりました。

あるときにサーバ再起動をする必要があり、再起動をおこなったところ、
httpdが自動起動しない状態になりました。

起動していなかったので、rootユーザになりサービスの起動をおこなったところ、
すでにポートが使われているような記述がみられました。下記になります。

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-137 ~]$ ps -ef | grep http
ec2-user  2392  2363  0 15:38 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto http


[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-137 ~]$ su
Password:
[root@ip-172-31-31-137 ec2-user]# service httpd start
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]

[root@ip-172-31-31-137 ec2-user]# lsof | grep http
sshd      2208     root    5u     IPv4               9642       0t0        TCP *:https (LISTEN)
sshd      2208     root    6u     IPv6               9644       0t0        TCP *:https (LISTEN)
sshd      2208     root    7u     IPv4               9646       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
sshd      2208     root    8u     IPv6               9648       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

プロセス番号をkillしてhttpdは開始できるようになりましたが、
サーバ再起動時に毎回この作業を行わないように設定できないでしょうか。

原因がなにであるのかご教示お願いしたく思います。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 一言で回答するのは難しいですが、TCPの接続がきちんと手順を踏んで切断されなかった時に、この問題は起きます。rootで`netstat -nop`するとどのプログラムがポートを握ってしまっているのか、あるいはプログラムは死んでいるけどtimeout待ちなのかわかります。-oはタイマーオプションで、後何秒で解放されるのか表示されます。

Comment: `grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config` を実行した結果を質問に追記してもらえませんか。

Answer (score 2):

ご質問の下記部分なのですが、sshdが80ポートと443ポートを
LISTENしているようにみえるのですが、sshdの設定は何か行われましたか？

```
[root@ip-172-31-31-137 ec2-user]# lsof | grep http
sshd      2208     root    5u     IPv4               9642       0t0        TCP *:https (LISTEN)
sshd      2208     root    6u     IPv6               9644       0t0        TCP *:https (LISTEN)
sshd      2208     root    7u     IPv4               9646       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
sshd      2208     root    8u     IPv6               9648       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Comment: まさかsshdが80,443を握っていると思わなかったので見落としましたが、確かに変ですね。ポートフォワードをしているならプロセス名はsshになるのでsshdがLISTENしているのは本当に変です。

Comment: Kenji Noguchiさん
suzukisさん
wakさん

Teratermから指定のポートで接続できるかどうかをためそうと思い、
Port 80を記述していたのが原因だったようです。

お騒がせしました。
ご回答ありがとうございます。

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-137 ~]$ grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Port 22
Port 443
Port 80
#GatewayPorts no